# Excel VBA running a macro across 50 sheets

Tags: vba, excel

In excel VBA, I am trying to run a simple autofilter across 50 sheets, however, it only runs it across one sheet. Can anyone help? The code is below:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

Dim wb As Workbook
   For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AC$91").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("11" _
        , "21", "22", "23", "31-33", "42", "44-45", "48-49", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "61" _
        , "62", "71", "72", "81"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Next wb
End Sub
```

Comment: You can just paste your code in as-is, highlight the entire code block, then hit the little `{}` button at the top. It will indent each line with 4 spaces and it will appear as code after submitting the post.

Comment: you need to go through each worksheet, you are going through each workbook in your workbook (which is 1).  You would be looking at more of a file folder path if you wanted to cycle through 50 workbooks.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is close, but... you are iterating through every `workbook` in the `application`. Instead you want to iterate through every `worksheet` in the `workbook`. Furthermore you have all this random `.Select` code in here. You don't need it. You just need to autofilter a range in each worksheet:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets        
      ws.Range("A1:AC91").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("11" _
        , "21", "22", "23", "31-33", "42", "44-45", "48-49", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "61" _
        , "62", "71", "72", "81"), Operator:=xlFilterValues        
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Nice and simple now as each line is clear. 1) Loop through each worksheet in the current workbook (`thisworkbook`). 2) Apply an autofilter to `A1:AC91`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed it in a jiffy.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you have a `For Each` loop that iterates over all open workbooks. I'm not sure if this is what you actually want or if it was an attempt to apply your logic to all sheets of a single workbook, but in any case, a `Workbook` has a collection called `Worksheets` over which you can iterate in the same way. Then inside that loop you'd just reference your worksheet loop variable instead of `ActiveSheet`. For instance:

```
' Here's your existing loop, which I don't know if you really want to keep or not.
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    ' Here's a loop that will access every sheet within the 'wb' workbook.
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ' Do your stuff here.
        ws.Cells(2, 2).Value = "Hello!"
    Next ws
Next wb
```